# Can I add/modify a static website policy on a bucket using awscli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to automate creating/uploading a website to a specified bucket in S3.

Say for example I have this policy template:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I create the bucket using:

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket $bucket --region eu-central-1 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=eu-central-1
```

How can I apply a policy to this bucket from a json string like the one above and also how to `enable website hosting` - all this using awscli not amazon gui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See commands under `aws s3api`:

```
$ aws s3api help | egrep -i "website|policy"
       o delete-bucket-policy
       o delete-bucket-website
       o get-bucket-policy
       o get-bucket-website
       o put-bucket-policy
       o put-bucket-website
```

For automating, I'd recommend dropping into a language. Python's boto3 is fantastic, the Ruby and Java SDKs are also very good.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I didn't do my homework very well before asking :-)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is interested in this approach, I ended up using (for now) the following commands:

```
bucket=$1
region=$2

# Create bucket
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket $bucket --region $region --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=$region

# Apply policy to allow get access to public
policy=$(cat /tmp/policy)
aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket $bucket --policy "$policy"

# Enable static hosting
aws s3 website s3://$bucket/ --index-document index.html

# Deploy app production distribution to new bucket
aws s3 cp dist/prod/ s3://$bucket --recursive

# See the results
open "http://$bucket.s3-website.$region.amazonaws.com"
```

But I'm accepting the other answer since this can grow to be very complex for more advanced requirements - compared to using boto3 in a python script that easily accepts different combinations of parameters e.g. skipping create bucket, reading default region from config etc.